# Erro quando tento rodar "Hello Word" em java, "Editor does not contain a main type"

Tags: java, eclipse

Gente, já reinstalei, fiz passo-a-passo com vídeos e não entendo porque está dando esse erro no eclipse. Diz o erro "Editor does not contains a main type" Coloquei dentro da pasta src, com package na hierarquia, tudo certo e fica dizendo isso: ''Editor does not contains a main type" e no console "No consoles to display at this time."

```
package com.hello;

public class HelloWord {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello world!");  
    }
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087008/10301489) te ajudaria?

Comment: yes! Thanks! Tentei fazer o caminho no Path das variáveis nas propriedades do sistema e funcionou.